# Inner static enum as generic type?

Tags: java, generics, static, enums, static-members

I am learning and experimenting with Java generics and come up with following piece of code which does not compile as expected. **`Result` cannot be resolved**.
`I` stands for input, `O` for output.

```
public interface Stats<I, O> {
    O addItem (int index, I item);
}

public class AStats implements Stats<Item, Result> {
    public static enum Result {
        SUCCESS1,
        SUCCESS2,
        ERROR;
    }

    @Override
    public Result addItem (int index, Item item) {
        //valid code
    }
}
```

- Is there more elegant solution than declaring `Result` in a separate file?
- Is it bad in general to have a method which returns an instance of generic type?

Comment: Note that enums are implicitly static.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Your classname is `AStats.Result`, not `Result`:

   ```
   public class AStats implements Stats<Item, AStats.Result> {
      ...
   }
   ```
2. I don't think that returning an instance of generic, inner type is a bad idea.